# How can I force support.microsoft.com to display KB entries in English?

Tags: localization, support.microsoft.com

My browser's language preferences are set to (in order): `[de-DE], [de], [en-US], [en]`, which works perfectly okay for 99,999% of websites I visit, since my mother tongue is German, with the notable exception of **Microsoft Knowledge Base (KB) articles** on http://support.microsoft.com/ which are mostly served as **unreadable poorly auto-translated articles**.

Therefore, I find myself constantly looking for the link to the untranslated version of the article. Until a month ago this was a single click, but has now become an arduous task, clicking *Article translations*, then searching for the right column and line containing *United States (English)*.

So, is there a possibility to force http://support.microsoft.com to always display KB entries in English? (Globally changing my language preferences is not an option, German is still preferred for mostly any other website. My browsers are Chrome and IE.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-to-set-default-language-for/193f8aee-dae0-44c9-9c75-11a7e0e49da4:

Go to http://support.microsoft.com and look at the very bottom left-hand corner of the page. There you will see a globe icon with the current region and language. Click that and choose your desired region/language. This change should persist between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

there are two things you can do:

1. Use bookmark workaround as suggested at [Chrome Extension for Switching Locale (Accept-Languages)](https://superuser.com/questions/478565/chrome-extension-for-switching-locale-accept-languages)
2. Write own extension for Chrome which will put proper Accept-Language into http request for particular regexp against hostname but be aware this is [area with some quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769061/how-to-add-custom-accept-languages-to-chrome-for-pseudolocalization-testing).
3. IE... is not my piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser addon to redirect `*suppport.microsoft.com/??-??/*` to `*suppport.microsoft.com/en-en/*`, making sure `*suppport.microsoft.com/en-en/*` itself is excluded.